# How to remote compile in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, cross-compiling, remote-debugging

I am developing an application using QtCreator in Mac OS X and it must be cross-platform.

I have a Mac OS X as host. Also I have a MS Windows installed on virtual machine and a Ubuntu installed on another virtual machine:

- Mac OS X: Qt 5.4.0 - 64bit - clang - Xcode 6.0
- MS Windows: Qt 5.3.0 - 32bit - VC++ 2013
- Ubuntu: Qt 5.3.0 - 64bit - GCC

How can I develop my application in Mac OS and build it in another platforms (Mac/Windows/Ubuntu) all at once?

Is there any remote compiler option in QtCreator?

Comment: In my last place, we had a cross compile environment.  I had a different make file per target architecture (which means a different .pro file).  You'll need a compiler that can compile for the target architectures AND any 3rd party libraries compiled for each platform.  Our environment got big.  AFAIK, QtCreator does not support this out of the box (but that's a guess).  Our environment was setup for C++ compilation in general, not just Qt.  Note that we had no Windows targets.  Only *nix.

Comment: Since you already have Virtual Machines containing the Qt build environment for the given OS, simply connect each one to Git, and when you need to build your changes, pull them from the remote repository to the virtual machine, then compile them on that VM.

Comment: @sashoalm, this is very manual! I look for an automated solution.

Comment: @S.M.Mousavi I understand that, it's just that I doubt a good solution exists. I'll bet in the end setting up the automated solution would require so much research and setting up it will end up costing you time not saving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can remote compile in Qt Creator but you can use a continuous build system like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) to setup a [distributed build environment](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds). Build slaves in all your VMs would compile on commit in your SCM like git or Subversion.

Advantages of this approach:

- works on all major platforms like Linux, MacOS, Windows
- .. and for all major compilers
- you can build on any number of platforms regardless of Qt Creator support
- you can get help easily because this is done in many professional systems
- you can distribute your development
- you can use any IDE
- you have great flexibility and tons of plugins which make life easy

Note: There are many more CI systems out there, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_continuous_integration_software).

Comment: It seems to be a good solution. I will check it. But remote build still will be useful in some cases.

Comment: That's right but that approach would be complicated and very limited. E.g. Qt Creator would have to be able to communicate with foreign compilers (e.g Visual Studio in different versions and for different architectures). 
When would you want to compile for all available platforms - on every compile for your host platform? Developing such a feature would not lead to a plugin for Qt Creator but to an independent tool which handles all cases. One of these tools is Hudson/Jenkins.

Comment: In debugging situations for example.

Comment: Debugging is still no problem: you develop, build and debug on your native host system just as you used to do. As soon as you want to build on any other platform you issue the builds manually or in a scheduled way. You can schedule the builds to take place at a given time (nightly build), after each commit, only manually and much more. You can also issue the builds when you start building in Qt Creator by adding a trigger build command to your custom build steps.So I guess you can realize any scenario that might be useful for you.

Answer (score 11):

I use remote compilation from Windows. I created custom build step using plink, which lest me execute remote command using key authorization, which starts the build. 
Qt creator can even parse errors returned :)

Short instruction how to configure it:

1. Create public key authentication for your user in putty and configure connection to your server:
   https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-configure-ssh-keys-authentication-with-putty-and-linux-server-in-5-quick-steps
2. Download plink:
   https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html
3. In your QtCreator project configure "Custom Process Step" to connect to your server and start compilation. 
   Assuming you have:

   - putty session to your build server configured and named *CentOS7_local*
   - user *usename*
   - project located in user home directory called *projectname*
     You can use something like (if you need some more sophisticated build start you can create a bash script on server and invoke it):

[image]

Comment: Could you write in detail how you did this? You'll get up-votes like hell!

Comment: To be honest (not sure if it would work but will try it out) I think that creating a normal remote deployment setup (Qt Creator allows you to set a target device, which in this case would be your container that you can expose to your localhost) would be a more popular solution that would not only allow remote building but also (if you have all the dependencies on your host where Creator is running) remote debugging via gdbserver running in the image that is loaded inside the container.